# How to swap indexes in a list of objects

Tags: vb.net

So I have a class as seen below:

```
Public Class parameters
    Public Property test As String
    Public Property test_type As String
    Public Property user_test_name As String
    Public Property meas As String
    Public Property spec_min As String
    Public Property spec_max As String
    Public Property spec_unit As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return user_test_name
    End Function
End Class
```

I have written each object in a list of objects and written them to a listbox.

I woould like to move the items in the list box up and down and I have done so by the following code successfully:

```
Private Sub up_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles up.Click
    'Move up

    'Make sure our item is not the first one on the list.
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

        Dim I = ListBox1.SelectedIndex - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Insert(I, ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = I
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub down_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles down.Click

    'Move down

    'Make sure our item is not the last one on the list.
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        'Insert places items above the index you supply, since we want
        'to move it down the list we have to do + 2
        Dim I = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 2
        ListBox1.Items.Insert(I, ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = I - 1

    End If
End Sub
```

But I would also like the actual indexes in the list to change as the selected item moves up or down. This way when im exporting the file I can keep the order that the user has selected. Please advise?

Comment: My thought (although there are many other ways to do this), maybe add in an integer `index` property to your class, then, set the index of the objects at the same time you're setting the index of the listbox. You can then always just sort your list via that property... Just a quick thought...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't swap indexes; swap values. Something like

```
Dim tempParam as parameters 

tempParam = myList(I)
myList(I) = myList(I-1)
myList(I-1) = tempParam
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using the datasource property.  The listbox will be populated with the tostring value of each item in the list(Params).  Now if you manipulate the list and reload the listbox they should stay in sync and you can save your list to a file.  To show more info in the listbox, just add it to the return value of the tostring method.

```
    Private Sub up_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles up.Click
        'Move up
        Dim TempParam As parameters = Params(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        'Make sure our item is not the first one on the list.
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

            Dim I = ListBox1.SelectedIndex - 1
            Params.Insert(I, TempParam)
            Params.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1)
            ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.DataSource = Params
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = I
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub down_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles down.Click

        'Move down
        Dim TempParam As parameters = Params(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        'Make sure our item is not the last one on the list.
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
            'Insert places items above the index you supply, since we want
            'to move it down the list we have to do + 2
            Dim I = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 2
            Params.Insert(I, TempParam)
            Params.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
            ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.DataSource = Params
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = I - 1

        End If
    End Sub

    Dim Params As New List(Of parameters)

    Private Sub save_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Params.AddRange({New parameters("Test1", "Test1a", "Test1b", "Test1c", "Test1d", "Test1e", "Test1f"), _
                         New parameters("Test2", "Test2a", "Test2b", "Test2c", "Test2d", "Test2e", "Test2f"), _
                         New parameters("Test3", "Test3a", "Test3b", "Test3c", "Test3d", "Test3e", "Test3f")})
        ListBox1.DataSource = Params
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class parameters
    Public Property test As String
    Public Property test_type As String
    Public Property user_test_name As String
    Public Property meas As String
    Public Property spec_min As String
    Public Property spec_max As String
    Public Property spec_unit As String
    Public Sub New(pTest As String, pTest_Type As String, pUser_Test_Name As String, pMeas As String, pSpec_Min As String, pSpec_Max As String, pSpec_Unit As String)
        test = pTest
        test_type = pTest_Type
        user_test_name = pUser_Test_Name
        meas = pMeas
        spec_min = pSpec_Min
        spec_max = pSpec_Max
        spec_unit = pSpec_Unit
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return user_test_name
    End Function
End Class
```